# ember-cli-scss compile error with SASS Lists and Maps

Tags: node.js, ember.js, sass, libsass

Given a `ember-cli` application with the `ember-cli-scss` addon and following SCSS Code containing a map:

```scss
$mdb-color: (
  "lighten-5":  #D0D6E2,
  "lighten-4":  #B1BACE,
  "lighten-3":  #929FBA,
  "lighten-2":  #7283A7,
  "lighten-1":  #59698D,
  "base":       #45526E,
  "darken-1":   #3B465E,
  "darken-2":   #2E3951,
  "darken-3":   #1C2A48,
  "darken-4":   #1C2331,
);
```

the compiler throws the error `Error: ("lighten-5": #fafafa, ...) isn't a valid CSS value.`

Changing the `node-sass` version to `3.13.0` via adding `node-sass` to the `package.json` and passing `node-sass` to the app config:

```scss
var nodeSass = require('node-sass');

var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    sassOptions: {
        nodeSass: nodeSass
    }
});
```

The error still occurs.

I'm sure that the `node-sass` version 3.13.0 will be used by ember-cli-scss with that configuration.

`node-sass` 3.13.0 uses `libsass` 3.3.6. Maps are supported since 3.1.

Is there something else to do in order to fix that issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the error message was somewhat misleading. The actual issue was that libsass couldn't compile MDBootstraps at all, the maps actually worked. However I'm note sure how to fix that.